# "Unfortunately, My LibGDX game has stopped" shows up on genymotion emulator

Tags: java, android, libgdx, emulation, genymotion

the game on libgdx installs in the emulator but is then the error shows up. The game works on my real nexus 4 device but not the emulator. is there any way to fix this? the code is below and the log cat is below the code.

```
package com.Redwanur.AndroidGame;

import java.io.IOException;

import com.Redwanur.Screens.MainMenu;
import com.Redwanur.Screens.PlayScreen;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Game;


public class AndroidGame extends Game {

Game game;

public void create() {      
    game = this;
    setScreen(new MainMenu(game));

}

public void dispose() {
    try {
        Score score = PlayScreen.getScore();
        score.saveScore(score.getHighscore());  
        System.out.print("saving end");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}

@Override
public void render() {          
    super.render();

}

@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {
}

@Override
public void pause() {
}

@Override
public void resume() {
}
}


12-31 18:37:36.482: D/dalvikvm(1204): Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/com.Redwanur.AndroidGame-2/libgdx.so 0xa5095408

12-31 18:37:37.238: A/libc(1204): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x000000b4 (code=1), thread 1204 (nur.AndroidGame)

12-31 18:37:41.342: D/dalvikvm(1225): Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/com.Redwanur.AndroidGame-2/libgdx.so 0xa5096298

12-31 18:37:41.522: A/libc(1225): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x000000b4 (code=1), thread 1225 (nur.AndroidGame)

12-31 18:46:18.978: D/dalvikvm(1272): Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/com.Redwanur.AndroidGame-2/libgdx.so 0xa5097128

12-31 18:46:19.786: A/libc(1272): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x000000b4 (code=1), thread 1272 (nur.AndroidGame)
```

Comment: Where is your code ?

Comment: @Charlie I just added it my bad

Comment: Are you using Gradle to build it? Are you sure you have all the native code in the correct directories?